# Does $f(z)=\frac{2z-1}{z^2(z-1)^2}$ have an antiderivative in given domain.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, indefinite-integrals

I have the following problem I'm having trouble with :

**Question** :

> Let $f(z)=\frac{2z-1}{z^2(z-1)^2}$ find the domain of $f$ : $D_f$ , does $f$ have an antiderivative in $D_f$

**Attempts** :

$D_f= \mathbb{C} $ \ {$0,1$}

First thing I did was rewriting  $f(z)$ using partial fractions I got :

$f(z)=\frac{2z-1}{z^2(z-1)^2} = \frac{1}{(z-1)^2}- \frac{1}{z^2}$ , but I got nothing( I thought using the linearity rules of integration proving that both $\frac{1}{z^2}$
and $\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}$ have one )

Or maybe should I use the residue theorem :  $\int_\gamma f(z)~\mathrm dz=2\pi i \sum_{k=1}^n\operatorname{Res}( f, z_k )\,\mathrm{Ind}_\gamma(z_k).$ ?

Any hint or help would be a lot appreciated , thanks in advance

Comment: Please keep in mind that I am totally ignorant of integration under Complex Analysis.  Why isn't the integral (i.e. the anti-derivative) simply $$\frac{-1}{(z-1)z} + C~?$$

Comment: Hello , don't worry no problem I'm also a beginner , how did you get that result , didn't you mean : $\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z-1}+C $

Comment: I used the work that you had already done re partial fractions, saw that each fraction was easily integrated, put the whole thing back together, and then manually observed that $$\frac{d}{dz} ~z(z-1) = \frac{d}{dz} ~(z^2 - z) = (2z - 1).$$  Then, it simply all clicked into place.

Comment: That is $$\frac{d}{dz} \frac{1}{g(z)} = \frac{-g'(z)}{\left[g(z)\right]^2}.$$

Comment: Oh now I see , but our teacher told us that in the complex plane , the integration rules are not more  the same that we used to know for $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Here are some examples  : a) If $f\colon U\to\mathbb C$ has an antiderivative $F$ on $U$ then $\displaystyle\int_\gamma f(z)~\mathrm dz=F(\gamma(b))-F(\gamma(a))$ along a smooth curve $\gamma\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb C$.
 \\\\\\ b) If $f$ has an antiderivative then $\displaystyle\int_\gamma f(z)~\mathrm dz$ depends only on the start and end point of the curve $\gamma$.
 \\\\\\ c) If $f$ has an antiderivative, then $\displaystyle\oint_\gamma f(z)~\mathrm dz=0$ for all closed curves $\gamma$.

Answer (score 1):

It is immediately obvious that $\frac{1}{(z-1)^2} - \frac{1}{z^2}$ has antiderivative $\frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{z-1}$, which is well defined on $D_f$. Lets say it isnt - the residue theorem tells us (since the residue of f around both of its’ poles is 0) that the integral of f on any closed curve in $D_f$ is 0 - which means f has an antiderivative in $D_f$